# Problem while trying to install Awesome-VM in Alpine Linux

Tags: installation, alpine-linux, xorg, awesome-wm

I'm trying to install the *Awesome VM* in *Alpine* Linux following [this tutorial](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Awesome(wm)_Setup).

I have passed the following commands:

```
$ sudo apk add awesome feh lxterminal
$ sudo apk add lua
$ setup-xorg-base
```

Then and all the commands in the "Start Your Desktop" section ...
... but when I pass this command :

```
$ startx
```

I got the following errors:

```
hostname: dev-box: Host not found
xauth: unable to link authority file /home/babonet13/.Xauthority, use /home/babonet13/.Xauthority-n
xauth: unable to link authority file /home/babonet13/.Xauthority, use /home/babonet13/.Xauthority-n

X.Org X Server 1.20.1
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.14.39-0-vanilla x86_64 Alpine Linux

Current Operating System: Linux dev-box 4.14.69-0-vanilla #1-Alpine SMP Mon Sep 10 19:33:23 UTC 2018 x86_64

Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=vmlinuz-vanilla root=UUID=26f38daa-766f-49f1-abb3-a0f7e8fc9d15 modules=sd-mod,usb-storage,ext4 nomodeset quiet rootfstype=ext4 initrd=initramfs-vanilla
Build Date: 30 August 2018 02:57:08PM
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Oct 5 13:33:54 2018
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
at http://wiki.x.org
for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
deallocvt: can't open console
```

Can could help me to start debugging it in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem installing X.org on Alpine Linux, you have not yet reached the point where Awesome is involved. I suggest you edit your post title and tags to reflect this. Also, stackoverflow is for programming question. If you have further installation issues, it is preferred to use [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/awesome-wm)

Nevertheless:

> (EE) no screens found(EE)

This is the error. It usually means you didn't install the video drivers *or* your kernel doesn't have the right modules *or* you use a static X.org build and it doesn't have the right compile options *or* you have a custum `xorg.conf`[.in] file that isn't representative of your setup.

/var/log/Xorg.0.log may have more information, but from my past experience with this kind of issue, wont provide more relevant details.

Also, it is AwesomeWM, not Awesome-VM.